# Shared workbook error when deleting checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, loops, runtime-error

Can Someone please tell me why the following code will run fine until I share the workbook? It runs until the point where it deletes the checkboxes. I can't figure out what's going on. As far as i know I'm not using any unsupported feature.

I get

> runtime error 1004

when deleting checkboxes

```
   Private Sub RunMe()

    Const BOX_SIZE As Integer = 16
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cbox As CheckBox
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim boxLeft As Double, boxTop As Double

    'Select Worsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sunday")

    'Clear Ranges that will be changed when CheckBoxes are clicked
    Worksheets("Sunday").Range("F2:G116").ClearContents
    Worksheets("Sunday").Range("I2:K116").ClearContents
    'Call FillDown

    'Delete checkboxes
    For Each cbox In ws.CheckBoxes
        cbox.Delete
    Next

    'Add checkboxes
    For i = 2 To 116
        For j = 8 To 8
            Set cell = ws.cells(i, j)
            With cell
                boxLeft = .Width / 2 - BOX_SIZE / 2 + .Left
                boxTop = .Height / 2 - BOX_SIZE / 2 + .Top
            End With
            Set cbox = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(boxLeft, boxTop, BOX_SIZE, BOX_SIZE)
            With cbox
                .Name = "CB" & i & j
                .Caption = ""
                .OnAction = "CheckBox_Clicked"
                .Placement = xlFreeFloating
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So where exactly does the error occur? Headline says "*when creating checkboxes*" text says "*where it deletes the checkboxes*". Please be clear about which line throws the error.

Comment: It's when it deletes the checkboxes. I finally figured out why. It's not letting me edit the checkboxes when the workbook is shared. i.e. i can't manually select or delete them either. But i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you define "shared workbook"? Are you using sharepoint? Is it a network share? And do you use any workbook or worksheet protection?

Comment: I'm sharing the workbook on a shared drive over the network and using the "Shared Workbook" feature in excel 2016

Comment: Then this might be a workbook protection issue. In the dialog of the shared workbook feature you should find a button like "workbook protection …" (I can't tell the exact wording because I use a german Excel). There you can allow the editing of objects. Then everybody should be able to delete the checkboxes. But I'm not 100% sure if it is possible at all that someone can delete the checkboxes in a shared workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this error finally by making the workbook exclusive and then sharing the workbook again once i was done adding the buttons.

```
Sub MakeExclusive()

    If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub MakeShared()

    If Not ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Name, accessmode:=xlShared
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I `call Sub MakeExclusive(`) on the first line of my sub and i `call MakeShared()` on the last line.